# IPhone SDK, Display an NSMutable array in Table view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk, nsmutablearray

i have tryed to display my NSMutableArray in a Table View by following a tutorial. It has completley failed for some reason, i think i have a good idea why but cannot get around it, this is my code:

```
- (void) scoreSystem {
scoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSNumber *onescore = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:score];
[scoreArray addObject:onescore];
NSNumber *twoscore = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:score];
[scoreArray addObject:twoscore];
NSNumber *threescore = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:score];
[scoreArray addObject:threescore];
NSNumber *fourscore = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:score];
[scoreArray addObject:fourscore];
NSNumber *fivescore = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:score];
[scoreArray addObject:fivescore];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [scoreArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];    
}
cell.textLabel.text = [scoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

I think it is because it wont let me link up everything properly in IB, it lets me put the data source and delegate to the Files owner, but then when i drag from the files owner to my view it says 'delegate' instead of 'view', i think its because i am doing it in the 'main window' not VC. 
Is there any way round this?
Thanks!
harry.

Comment: Is scoreSystem called in viewDidLoad?  Try `scoreArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain];`

Comment: Please don't try that. alloc / init will retain the array, the extra retain will cause a leak.

Comment: Either place a breakpoint or NSLog in the numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath an insure they are being called.  Also insure that numberOfSectionsInTableView returns a non-zero value.  If these are not getting called, insure that your table view dataSource is properly connected to your TableViewController.

Report back.  :)

Comment: Tom, you're right.  I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: I'm completely confused to why it isn't working, so i am going to try and display the array in a different way. Does anyone know of a way to display a NSMutableArray in a plain textView or something? :/ 
Thanks
Harry

Comment: Any other way to display a NSMutableArray?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the class that your code is in as the tableview's datasource. Create an instance of your class in IB (use the NSObject, and rename its class to YourClass).

This will create an instance of your class that will be available when the nib is decoded.

Then, control-drag from the tableview to your class, and set the datasource.

That's it! You should be able to set breakpoints in your -numberOfRowsInSection: method above, and see it called as soon as the table view comes in view. If you don't, check your connections and check for typos: the runtime is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Well for some reason someone bumped this old thread.  I might as well chime in.  The reason this code has problems is because it is trying to set the `text` property of the cell to a `NSNumber`.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [scoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Try this instead:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[scoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];
```